# Desktop Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Login

Tags: login, password

How can I make a login into my desktop Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS only from my office and block it off from anywhere else?

Comment: What do you understand as "anywhere else"? Is this a laptop that is being moved? Please describe your use case more explicitly. It is currently unclear what you precisely want. Please edit the title of your question to reflect the actual question better.

Comment: So, it is a desktop, not movable. By "anywhere else", I mean hackers, the bastards who visited me more than once. On the other hand, a complicated password that I have to print many a time a day is a tedious business.

Comment: What you're asking about sounds like setting up a firewall. A firewall can block certain ports, so no outside access is possible (for instance blocking the SSH port). Please research this subject, you can [start here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVsMaXQkktQ) (this is for servers, but applies to desktops as well).

Comment: Also, do a [port scan](https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap) on your outside IP address. If any open ports show up, it's cause for concern.

Comment: The question is not really answerable in its current form, as it is too broad. Does "make a login" mean using SSH? Or some (which?) remote login software? Or only physically?

Comment: The Firewall was set and got passed through. Will try <port scan>. What is SSN? Any "remote login" is not presumed by the question.

Comment: If the firewall got passed through, I'd say it isn't really effective. Firewalls come in 2 types - software and hardware. It would be good for you to know which hardware firewall you have between your office and the internet?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to setup a Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) system such as Google Authenticator. In this way, you'd have to use **a time-based code from your phone** in addition to your password each time you want to login. Without the codes provided by your phone, no one will be able to login into your system.

**Instructions for Ubuntu 20.04.3:**

1. Install Google Authenticator on your phone ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2)) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-authenticator/id388497605)).
2. Make sure Ubuntu is fully updated:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

3. Install Google Authenticator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
```

4. Now you have to configure Google Authenticator. You do this for the current user, so no `sudo` here. For this, enter the command:

```
google-authenticator
```

5. To the question `Do you want authentication tokens to be time-based (y/n)`, answer “yes” by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Now the Terminal will print a QR code (a big one), followed by your secret key and emergency codes. **Scan the QR code** or enter your secret key into the Google Authenticator app on your phone. Also, print or write down these codes and **keep them in a safe place.** You will need these codes to access your computer in case you lose your phone.
7. Answer the next four questions according to your preferences. It is safe to select "yes" to all four of them, again by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but you can select whatever suits you the most.

> **Note:** If you have multiple users in your system which are allowed to login, you will need to configure `google-authenticator` (steps 4 to 7) for each of them before continuing with the next steps.

8. Now you have to edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file to configure your system to use Google Authenticator for authentication. To do this, enter in the Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

9. In the `nano` text editor that opens, use the arrow keys to go down to the line that says:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the “Primary” block)
```

10. Add the following line below that one:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

It should look like this:
[image: auth required pam_google_authenticator.so]

11. Save the file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. **Do not close the file or this Terminal yet!**
12. Open a different Terminal and try your setup by running `sudo whoami`. You should be asked for your verification code from your phone, then for your password. If authentication is successful, you can proceed. If not, comment the line that you just inserted in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` by inserting a `#` in front of it, then save the file again by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. **Something was wrong with your setup.**
13. Finally close the file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

> **Caution!** For SSH access, you also need to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` from `no` to `yes`, then restart the `ssh` service, i.e. `sudo service ssh restart`. Otherwise you won't be able to login via SSH.

After you follow these steps, your system will first ask you for the Verification Code from your phone before letting you enter your password whenever it is required to do so (for login, unlock, `su`, `sudo`, `ssh`, etc.).

[image: Verification Code]

[image: Password]

If you ever lose your phone, use the secret key to configure Google Authenticator on a new phone. Alternatively, you can use one of the recovery keys to login, then run `google-authenticator` again to setup a new secret key with your new phone.

**Source:** [How To Enable Two Factor Authentication On Linux To Log In (AddictiveTips)](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-two-factor-authentication-on-linux-to-log-in/)

Comment: While the intention of this answer is excellent, I believe this should be in addition to having a proper firewall configured first. 2FA does not help against other vulnerabilities accessible from the outside.

Comment: While your statement is true and I completely agree that a firewall must be used to prevent vulnerability exploit from the outside, the question is specifically regarding login prevention, not vulnerability exploit prevention, which is a different topic. Using 2FA wont block logins from the "outside", but it will block logins from anyone not having immediate access to your phone, wherever you are.

Comment: Moreover, this answer does not cover other necessary security measures such as device encryption. Without encryption on your device, it would be trivial to use a Live USB to access your files or remove Google Authenticator from your system if the attacker has physical access to your device. But that is a different topic too.

Comment: I agree with you. But the question is currently phrased as "... and block it off from anywhere else", which I'm reading as "blocking from the outside". However, your answer is still very good, so upvoted. 

Comment: In fact your answer is so good I've bookmarked it, in case I would need to enable 2FA myself at some point.

Comment: Alejandro, <You may want to setup a Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) system such as Google Authenticator. In this way, you'd have to use a time-based code from your phone in addition to your password each time you want to login. Without the codes provided by your phone, no one will be able to login into your system.> Once you said "such as Google Authenticator", does it mean that there are other Authenticators? I avoid Google because in our lands it means Google UA or Google RU. Both carry a lot of garbage. So, any other 2FA?

Comment: Google Authenticator is an implementation of the TOTP algorithm. You don't have to use the Google App, you can use other 2FA apps supporting TOTP (for instance 1Password).